# How to view permissions data on a screen in activiti BPM + spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, activiti

I have a hiring process for a developer. As below:

[image]

Step 1: Human Resource entered job seekers' information and their salary information on a screen.

(Problem in step 2)
Step 2: Also on the screen, I want to show only job seeker information for Tech Interview and show full information for HR management. How to implement it on spring boot + activiti BPM?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom API to fetch variables (in which job applicants details are stored) that filters data from the 1st section. call that api from your UI. In the HR Management call the out of the box API to get All Variables. [see](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_rest_support)

Alternatively, you can filter variables on front-end based on User's role.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Do you have any examples?